# c++ singly linked list using two classes

Tags: c++, list, class, templates

So I'm using my book from class to create a singly linked list, but i can't get it to compile. I get 20+ errors for syntax and at this point I'm not sure what to do. I must use two classes though.

```
template <typename E> 
class Node {
private:
    E elem;
    Node<E>* next;
    friend class SLinkedList<E>;
};

template <typename E> 
class SLinkedList {
public:
    SLinkedList();
    ~SLinkedList();
    bool empty() const;
    const E& front() const;
    void addFront(const E& e);
    void removeFront();
```

Comment: The *first* thing you should do is post those "20+ errors for syntax" :-)

Comment: Also include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And your code doesn't look complete. Is that what you have in your source file?

Comment: So the main issue i run into is that there's a syntax error when I make SLinkedList a friend of Node. it says syntax error '<'

Comment: at the very least you're missing a brace to end `class SLinkedList`.